Superconducting ground-state and Higgs mechanism
I found this article on spontaneous symmetry breaking in superconductors. Using the same arguments as Weinberg, the author demonstrates that the properties of a superconductor are the consequences of the Higgs mechanism, i.e. the appearance of massive photons in superconductors. In section 8, the author states in particular that the fundamental state of the superconductor is unique and that the angle of the order parameter is a gauge parameter. All this is consistent with Elitzur's theorem (there is also this article which confirms the absence of SSB in a superconductor).
But this is a priori in contradiction with BCS theory, which presents a continuous degeneracy of the ground state parametrised by a $\phi$ angle. Moreover, this degeneracy is necessary to understand the Josephson effect, which is proportional to the phase difference between 2 superconductors interacting by tunneling.
My questions are therefore :

Is the ground state degenerate in a superconductor or not?
If so, how is this consistent with Elitzur's theorem?
If not, how can the Josephson effect be explained?

Edit : I just found this article where the author says "[...] a superfluid, and in particular a superconductor, is characterized by a spontaneously broken symmetry, and, at least in the thermodynamic limit, there are many degenerate ground states."
There are therefore 2 opposing points between the articles, who is right ?


Is the ground state degenerate in a superconductor or not?

No, it is not. As your first linked article explains, configurations of the order parameter which differ by a global phase factor can be obtained from one another via gauge transformation, and therefore correspond to precisely the same physical state.

If not, how can the Josephson effect be explained?

The supercurrent $\mathbf J_s$ is given by
$$\mathbf J_s = \frac{e^*}{m^*}\left(\hbar \nabla \phi + e^*\mathbf A\right)|\psi|^2$$
where $e^*$ and $m^*$ are the effective charge and mass of the Cooper pairs.
A gauge transformation takes the form
$$\mathbf A \mapsto \mathbf A + \nabla \lambda$$
$$\varphi \mapsto \varphi - \frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t}$$
$$\psi \mapsto \mathrm{exp}[iq \lambda] \psi \implies \phi \mapsto \phi + q\lambda$$
where $\mathbf A$ and $\varphi$ are the vector and scalar potentials and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary scalar function of space and time.  As you can see, a spatially uniform rotation of the order parameter simply corresponds to taking $\lambda$ to be a (nonzero) constant.
In the absence of an electromagnetic field, it is natural to take $\mathbf A$ and $\varphi$ to be zero everywhere. In this choice of gauge, $\mathbf J_s = \frac{e^*\hbar}{m}\nabla \phi$ and the supercurrent is driven by the phase gradient across the junction. However, one could make a gauge transformation to remove the phase gradient entirely (i.e. by taking $\lambda = - \phi/q$) in which case  $\mathbf J_s = e^{*2}\mathbf A |\psi|^2/m$ and the supercurrent is driven by the non-zero vector potential.

Thanks! To make sure I have understood: let's say I take two superconductors completely isolated from each other and slowly bring them together until I create a junction. If the electromagnetic field is zero, do we agree that I won't observe a Josephson current?

@Jean If the electromagnetic field is exactly zero everywhere, then I would agree. In real life, however, fluctuations in the electromagnetic field would effectively randomize the relative phase between the two superconductors. A more realistic experiment would be to imagine creating a large superconducting loop containing a single JJ and then letting it cool through Tc; it is entirely possible for persistent currents to spontaneously develop in such systems.
